# How can I programatically log another user out in D7?

Tags: sessions, users

On our site we have client accounts, each with a super administrator and sub users belonging to that account.

We want the super admin to be able to force sub users to log out. What's the best way to destroy a user's session in Drupal that works regardless of whether the session information is stored in Redis, Memcache or the database?

Before someone feels tempted to suggest user_logout(), that destroys the *current* user's session. I want the current user to be able to destroy a *different* user's session!

Comment: Nearly sure we already have a question about this.  I know I have a patch in drush-extras to be able to do this, but it hasn't been committted.

Comment: I googled around and searched around DA, but no luck. I'll review your patch.

EDIT: Your patch unfortunately only handles the the database case. We were hoping to use memcache given the large number of users / sessions!

Comment: I believe blocking/unblocking the user has the same effect (except they'll probably get an e-mail notification of the unblocking). You could probably use `hook_mail_alter()` to intercept that e-mail and suppress it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`drupal_session_destroy_uid()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/drupal_session_destroy_uid/7) sounds like a safe bet:

> Ends a specific user's session(s).

The core implementation clears the database, as you'd expect, but any module that overrides session.inc, and doesn't provide a working implementation of that function, would surely be considered broken (as `user_delete_multiple()` and other functions need it).

So in theory you should be able to use that function regardless of the storage.

Comment: vote up, this is good solution

Comment: This is the correct solution! For future readers, it is implemented in memcache. See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/memcache/tree/unstable/memcache-session.inc#n356

Answer (score 1):

[Session Proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_proxy) provides a generic replacement for Drupal's session handling that is supposed to work with various backends.
As such it also implements [`drupal_session_destroy_uid()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/session_proxy/tree/session.inc?h=7.x-1.0-rc1#n94).

Note that the session implementation of [Memcache API and Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache) is considered [unstable](https://www.drupal.org/node/656838), and that the maintainer of [Redis](https://www.drupal.org/project/redis) [recommends](https://www.drupal.org/node/2250195#comment-8736079) the use of *Session Proxy*.

The problems of handling sessions consistently across various backends are outlined in [issue 1260634](https://www.drupal.org/node/1260634).

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, We can log out a user if we have his User_ID using db_delete():

```
db_delete('sessions')->condition('uid', $User_ID)->execute();
```